# how to prevent to close jquery div popup after click on submit button

Tags: jquery, html

Here is code

```html
<HTML>
    <head>
      <style>
          #log{display:none;}
      </style>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
      </script>
      <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
              $("a").click(function(){
                  $("#log").show();
              });
          });
       </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript:;">Log In</a>
    <div id="log">
       <form action="abc.php" method="post">
          <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Email ID"> <br><br>
          <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Login">
       </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

When I click on submit button, the div popup closes automatically.

Comment: Is that your full jQuery code?

Comment: You might want to change the type submit to button and add ajax call to post this form

Comment: i want that when i click on submit it show me validation text without post to next page

Comment: you code as is, does not show any div popup that seems to the be the issue you want to resolve. please give us all related code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to change the type submit to button and add ajax call to post this form (I didn't run the code, but the approach is to change the button type from submit to button and accomplish the task with ajax call, that way the page won't refresh and you can show next whatever you like) :

```
   <HTML>
        <head>
          <style>
              #log{display:none;}
          </style>
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
          </script>
          <script>
              $(document).ready(function(){
                  $("a").click(function(){
                      $("#log").show();
                  });

                  $("#loginButton").click(function(event) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url : "abc.php",
                        type : "post",
                        data : {
                            user : $("[name=user]").val(),
                            pass: $("[name=pass]").val()
                        },
                        dataType : 'json',
                        success : function(data) {
                                // show your validation text
                        }
                    });
                  });
              });
           </script>
        </head>
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:;">Log In</a>
        <div id="log">
           <form action="abc.php" method="post">
              <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Email ID"> <br><br>
              <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
              <input id="loginButton" type="button" value="Login">
           </form>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Where is your popup div?

Comment: popup div is with id="log"

Comment: Are you sure there is no other js error / syntax error? Please verify in your browser.. It shouldn't reflect popup appearance

Comment: sorry but no other error in my code. when i remove your code it show me div popup.

Comment: @ManishSuthar I had some redundant bracket in my code, please check again (the closing bracket in success function appear twice..

Comment: Can you explain it with php ? i did not use Ajax before.

Comment: @ManishSuthar It's not about PHP (server side), the idea of ajax is to communicate with the server without submitting the page each time, its happand behind the scenes . If its help you it would be nice if you mark the solution as solved...

Answer (score 0):

I've added an ID to your form to give it a distinct selector, and then attached an event on form submit to hide the form.

```html
<HTML>
    <head>
      <style>
          #log{display:none;}
      </style>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
      </script>
      <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){
              $("a").click(function(){
                  $("#log").show();
              });
              $("#myForm").on("submit", function() {
                  $("#log").hide();
              });
          });
       </script>
    </head>
<body>
    <a href="javascript:;">Log In</a>
    <div id="log">
       <form action="abc.php" method="post" id="myForm">
          <input type="text" name="user" placeholder="Email ID"> <br><br>
          <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password"><br><br>
          <input type="submit" value="Login">
       </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks but i don't want to hide div , div will stay there after i click on submit.